# How To Redirect Any Request For The Domain To example.html

Tags: php, html, redirect

I want to redirect all the files of the site to a specify html file

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using only HTML and JS, but you can achieve this using `.htaccess` [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/<somepage> [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks FarSide for helping with my first answer :)

Comment: Internal Server Error appeared :(

Comment: You need to change `example.com` with your website or `localhost`.

Comment: And change `<somepage>` with `example.html` or other